# Save and close word document when using win32com

Tags: python, ms-word, syntax-error, win32com

I want to make sure I save the word document and close it right after so I can further edit it in the next command in python.

```
from win32com import client
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Summary_output.docx")
book = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\summary3.xlsx")
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1:G5").Copy()    
wdRange = doc.Content
wdRange.Collapse(0)
wdRange.PasteExcelTable(False, False, False) 
book.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\summary3.xlsx")
book.Close()
excel.Quit()

doc.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Summary_output.docx")
```

I don't think this last line is correct.
What's the right way of saving and closing the word document? Thank you.

Comment: why do You think that it is not the correct way of doing that? although it doesn't seem to close anything it should at least save the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you save the document you should close it, pretty similar to what you have done with the Excel Workbook, so your code should be:

```
from win32com import client
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Summary_output.docx")
book = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\summary3.xlsx")
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1:G5").Copy()    
wdRange = doc.Content
wdRange.Collapse(0)
wdRange.PasteExcelTable(False, False, False) 
book.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\summary3.xlsx")
book.Close()
excel.Quit()
doc.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Summary_output.docx")
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```